# Best way to change categories of multiple columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say i have this dataframe:

```
dfa = pd.DataFrame({'s1': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 's2': ['a', 'c', 'd']}, dtype='category')
```

in the column s1, i would like to change:

```
a -> 1
b -> 2
c -> 3
```

in the column s2 i would like to make this replacement:

```
a -> 10
b -> 40
c -> 50
```

If i had multiple categories and multiple columns (s1,s2,s3..sn) with multiple categories, what would  be the easiest way to make this replacement?

I know that i could use:

```
dfa[['s1']] = dfa['s1'].replace([['a','b','c'],[1,2,3])
```

But there is a better way of doing this for all columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass `dict` when `replace` let the column name as first key

```
out = dfa.replace({'s1':dict(zip(['a','b','c'],[1,2,3])),
                   's2': dict(zip(['a','b','c'],[10,40,50]))})
Out[207]: 
   s1  s2
0   1  10
1   2  50
2   3   d
```

Comment: What if i would like to change all the categories 'a' 'b' and 'c' into one single category 'a' ?